# Ninject SingetonScope doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

So I have some singletons defined in my Ninject modules like this:

```
Kernel.Bind<IDataStoreMainainance>().To<DataStoreMainainance>().InSingletonScope();
```

However for some classes it seems to completely ignore the singleton and creating a new instance each time. I've used it before without issue. This is a console app int .net 4.0 with Ninject 3.2.2.

I have seen some people suggest using ToConstant, but the objects I am creating have there own fairly complex dependencies so this isn't a very useful approach.

Edit:
So I found this bug https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/issues/221 it looks like InSingletonScope is bugged and nobody is looking at fixing it. Any good workarounds?

Comment: "However for some classes it seems to completely ignore the singleton". Please show those classes.

Comment: Does your code actually use `OnActivation` as described in the bug report? If so, please show that code. If not, why are you mentioning this?

Comment: You probably have multiple kernels.The singleton is only unique in the kernel scope.